# Make FirebaseAnimatedList auto scroll when have new data

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've try to build Chat example on Flutter, but I have problem, how I can make FirebaseAnimatedFlutter auto scroll when have new data populate ?

Example: When I submit new chat message for my friend, from my side, I can call this method to auto scroll:

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    scrollController.animateTo(
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.easeOut);
  });
```

But at my friend side, he still need manual scroll to end to see new message

So, there are anyway to detect and auto scroll to end of FirebaseAnimatedList when we receive new data ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see all your code, but there is a trick you can do that will avoid having to add extra code. It involves reversing the data in the list of messages and setting to `true` the `reverse` property of the `ListView`. This will make the messages move up as new messages come in.

You reverse the original list, you set to `true` the `reverse` property of the `ListView`, and when you add messages to your List you use `messages.insert(0, newMessage)` to add it to the top (now bottom because of inversion), instead of of `messages.add`.

```
class Issue65846722 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Issue65846722State createState() => _Issue65846722State();
}

class _Issue65846722State extends State<Issue65846722> {
  List<String> messages = [
    'message 1',
    'message 2',
    'message 3',
  ].reversed.toList();
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('StackOverflow'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            // To simulate an incoming message from another source that is not
            // the local TextField
            child: Icon(Icons.message),
            onPressed: () => newMessage('new message'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: messages.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Container(
                  child: Text(messages[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.black,),
          TextFormField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            onFieldSubmitted: (_) => submitMessage()
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void submitMessage(){
    newMessage(textEditingController.text);
    textEditingController.clear();
  }

  void newMessage(String newMessage){
    setState(() {
      messages.insert(0, newMessage);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i use FirebaseAnimatedList, and i want to auto scroll to end, not reverse list

Comment: By reversing the data and the list, your `ListView` will always be scrolled down to the end.

Comment: @EddyLee I've added a full example of what I was speaking about in regards to reversing.

Comment: ^^ Work fine with list view, i will apply it for FirebaseAnimatedList

Comment: @EddyLee I'm glad I could help. I would advise you to add to your original question the information you added below as an Answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

thank for useful answer of João Soares, i already solve this problem by 2 step

1. Reverse data from Firebase by use 'sort' property of FirebaseAnimatedList
2. Set 'reverse' property to 'true' in FirebaseAnimatedList
   And work like a charm

   ```
   FirebaseAnimatedList(
   query: loadChatContent(context, app),
   sort: (DataSnapshot a,DataSnapshot b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key), //fixed
   reverse: true, //fixed
   ```

Comment: Ehy, I implemented your solution but animated list is acting weird. When a new message comes, the first message in chronological order (the one at the top) disappears. Every time I get a new message, the oldest one on top disappears. Do you have this problem too?

Comment: I actually think I get an exception: 'index != null && index >= 0': is not true

Comment: @EddyLee Is your code still working or have you updated your firebase packages and are you now seeing the exception: 'index != null && index >= 0': is not true  ? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @glos - I am also getting this error from Firebase Animated List in code that used to work fine (early 2021). I suspect a bug has been introduced with Flutterfire updates to the database package. Did you find a solution to this? I am struggling.
JS - do you have any insight here that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your FirebaseAnimatedList with Flexible Widget & thats it.
This worked for me.